# After converting date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format result comes in to "MM-dd-yyyy"

Tags: c#

I want to convert my date in to **MM/dd/yyyy** format.i use following code for converting date

```
 string NewDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(Mydate, englishCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", englishCulture);
```

but the result is comes like this **04-02-2016**

i want to having result in **04/02/2016** in string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
 string NewDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(Mydate, englishCulture).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes around the [delimiters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

```
string NewDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(Mydate, englishCulture).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", englishCulture);
```

Alternatively,

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-UK");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";

string NewDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(MyDate,dtfi).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", dtfi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateSeparator property of DateTimeFormatInfo. For more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130987(v=vs.110).aspx

```
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-UK");
        DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;
        dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";

        string NewDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(MyDate,dtfi).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", dtfi);
```